# How do I do GridSearchCV() on svm.SVR()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, hyperparameters

Say I have

```
param_grid = { 
     "C": [1, 2, 3, 4]
     "gamma": [0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 1]
     "kernel": ["rbf", "linear", "poly", "sigmoid"]
```

When running gridsearchCV it doesnt work because "linear" kernel doesnt use "gamma".
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can define disjoint grids as a list:

```py
param_grid = [
    {
        "C": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "gamma": [0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 1],
        "kernel": ["rbf", "poly", "sigmoid"],
    },
    {
        "C": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "kernel": ["linear"],
    },
]
```